# turning TFT on/off using MOSFET

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, touchscreen

I want to be able to turn TFT screen on and off using MCU. Is it safe to put a FET on the ground line of TFT and drive it from MCU, by disconnecting and connecting ground from the screen? or should I use p-type feet on power line to switch it? I am not sure if it's a good idea to leave TFT internal electronic's floating.

EDIT: LCD TFT 2,4"240x320 Arduino shield, MCU is barebone Arduino(Atmega328P) and FET i planned to use is 2N7000.

Comment: LCD monitor and TV designers tend to switch the positive line of the TFT's supply via a P-ch. MOSFET. IRF9335 is commonly used in most of LCD TVs and monitors for this purpose. Please note that switching TFT's supply off does not turn off the backlight. You may also want to switch it off as well.

Comment: Please define TFT to clarify the question.  An N-channel FET is typically used as a low side switch, not a P-channel FET.

Comment: TFT thin-film transistor active matrix LCD display.

Comment: if you also float (or set to the same voltage as the supply) all the I/O that's going to the display, switching the power at the low side should be OK.

Comment: Find out how much current your TFT is using, and at what voltage. Then read the datasheet for the 2N7000, and find out if it will support your voltage and current. Then look for a different FET.